# title for td using fmt:message

Tags: html, button, html-table, title

I want to add one title for one button which is inside one td of HTML table using fmt:message key="..."

How can I do that :I put in this way but it gives me error

```
            data=data+"<td><button title="<fmt:message key="Modifica.Dettagli.Attività" />" onclick='displayModify("+rs.getString(1)+")' style='border:none;background-color:transparent;background-image:url(../images/modify_20.png);width:20px;height:20px'></button></td>";
```

enter code here

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: `<ftm:message ...` isn’t HTML; please tag your question properly. And show the error message.

Comment: yes I know it is not a html tag...my question is here how can I insert it in one button tile, is it possible? if no,is there any suggestion for translating the title of buttons?Let me tell you that "data" here is one jsp variable
Error:
Multiple annotation found at this line:
-syntax error on token ">",delete this token
-syntax error on token ":" , ; expected